# How can I speed up UIView snapshotting?

Tags: objective-c, performance

I am prototyping a fun UI transition that requires me to subdivide arbitrary view controllers into slices. I'm currently snapshotting the view and using the resultingImage as the .content of a bunch of CALayers. Works great, except it seems to take 0.25-0.5 seconds on an iPhone 4 (iOS 5.1) to snapshot which makes the user experience far from fluid. I am using the standard approach:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Is there a faster way to grab a snapshot than this? The views being snapshotted will usually contain a dozen views and images, many of which have transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling shouldRasterize on your CALayer?